# Can Kitty Pryde phase through material attached to her (e.g. Toad's slime)

Tags: marvel, x-men, toads-spit

If Kitty Pryde has some material directly attached to her, can she phase through the material and leave it behind? Or would the material phase with her?

It has been shown that she *can* phase other objects she's wearing (like her clothes) or holding, and other people she's touching, through solid material. How much control does she have over which materials do any don't phase with her?

For example, suppose Toad were to attack her and cover her face with his hardened slime, so she couldn't breathe. Would she be able to phase through the slime, letting it fall off of her, or would she need someone else to come along and remove it?

Comment: @JackBNimble: I think it is, in some ways, a straightforward question regarding what her powers can and cannot do. Can she selectively not phase things on her such as restraints or hardened slime (on a side not, do not search for "Kitty Pryde gag" to look for image reference if you value your browsing history purity).

Comment: OP: I tried to expand on the question to get to what *I think* is the heart of what you're asking, and get rid of the somewhat frowned-upon "who would win, X vs Y" style. Please feel free to edit it further if I missed the point.

Comment: I appreciate the change; you gave it more meaning. So, thanks, Michael

Comment: Dear Michael E. Any thoughts on what Paige Guthrie's (Husk) limitations would be in a similar attack by Toad?

Comment: I have no particular opinion on the answers; there are other users FAR more versed on Marvel canon than I, but I suspect Husk could simply rip her own skin off, possibly turning into something non-adhesive. If you want to know, that warrants a separate question.

Comment: I don't remember enough to put this as an answer, but maybe someone else can run with it. I remember in one of the movies/cartoons they're hiding out in a cave, and she's trying to hold a radio just right to pick up a broadcast. Once she gets the position right, Iceman or someone encases her in ice and she phases out, leaving the radio in the right place.

Answer (score 5):

I'm having trouble finding any solid proof, but I *suspect* the answer is yes, given what we know about her abilities.

The main question here is; **Can Kitty phase through something that's already "attached" to her?** The specific case you asked about, fending off an attack by Toad, would be one good case. But there are even simpler situations we could imagine her being in. For example, could she phase herself through *handcuffs*?

### Escaping Restraints

Oddly enough, I was unable to find any canonical situations where Kitty Pryde was restrained in that fashion (there must be one, I can't imagine that it has never happened in all of her 35 year history) however, I was able to find one *non-canon* case where it happened, which may give us some clues.

In the crossover series [*The Uncanny X-Men and the New Teen Titans*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Uncanny_X-Men_and_The_New_Teen_Titans), Kitty is one of the X-Men taken hostage by Darkseid. She is chained up to a wall and attempts to phase herself out of the cuffs. In this particular case she was unable to do so, **but only because Darkseid made the cuffs out of special ultra-dense material that she could not phase through**.

The implication here is that, if they were normal cuffs, *she could have escaped*. Given that the series was largely written by Chris Clairemont, probably the best-known X-Men writer ever, I think we can safely accept that his vision of Kitty's powers here would match her canon abilities.

[image]

### Similar Abilities

Beyond her potential ability to escape restraints, Kitty is definitely shown to have learned exceptional control over her phasing ability. For example, she has always been able to phase her clothes, but had to *learn* to phase other objects. Otherwise, the objects would simply fall through her hands (or whatever). Eventually, of course she was able to phase whole groups of people, but in those cases she had to actively choose to do so.

She also has control over which parts of her body phase. For example, she's been shown capable of phasing her arm through the wall such that only the part that intersects the wall is intangible (she punched someone on the other side this way).

### Conclusion

Thus, given what we *have* seen her capable of, I would imagine that she is fully capable of phasing herself out of anything that she gets caught in. I think it would be entirely in line with her previous abilities that she could, for example, just phase out her head, allowing Toad's spittle to fall harmlessly off.

But, as we've also seen, there are limits. There are some things she simply cannot phase through. I highly doubt Toad's spittle has neutron-star-level density, but since I can't find any evidence that it's actually *happened*, we can't know for sure.

Comment: Kitty has always had problems with denser material,

Comment: @cde that's true, but she could still phase through most things, just with more effort and/or a bit of pain. I know adamantium gives her trouble but she can do it -- she's phased through Wolverine before.

Comment: Interesting. However, Kitty has also been shown phasing things involuntarily (e.g. other people and her clothes).

Comment: After a bit of research, I remembered that, like Emma Frost, Jean Grey, and others, one defining aspect of Kitty's phasing power is concentration (e.g. if the character is being suffocated, it would weaken her concentration). That being said, in the tv show X-Men: Evolution, Kitty shows concentration high enough to phase the X-Jet (and all aboard) through a mountain.

Answer (score 2):

If the screenshot below is any indication, if Toad managed to catch Kitty Pryde out of breath and slime her before she could inhale, then no. As the caption states: Not being able to inhale makes it kind of hard on the girl to phase 'erself. (The caption are Paige Guthrie's view on the issue, hence the accent.)

[image]

Comment: Does that mean she couldn’t, or just that it’ll be harder?

Comment: Hard to say, due to this being the only time I recall her being put in such a situation. (Also, as clarification, that is Skin who caught her off-guard; don't know if anyone caught that).